# unordered key_type for non library types requires hash<> specialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, xerces-c

I'm trying to create an std::unordered_map with xercesc::XMLUri as the key type.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include "xercesc/util/XMLUri.hpp"

int main()
{
        std::unordered_map<xercesc::XMLUri,xercesc::XMLUri> uriMap;
}
```

resulting in the following :

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -O0 -emit-llvm -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -I/usr/include ../xx.cpp 
In file included from ../xx.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/unordered_map:43:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/bits/functional_hash.h:59:7: error: static_assert failed "std::hash is not specialized for this type"
  static_assert(sizeof(_Tp) < 0,
  ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/bits/unordered_map.h:45:32: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::hash<xercesc_3_1::XMLUri>' requested here
                       integral_constant<bool, !__is_final(_Hash)>,
                                                ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/bits/unordered_map.h:263:14: note: in instantiation of default argument for '__unordered_map<xercesc_3_1::XMLUri, xercesc_3_1::XMLUri, std::hash<xercesc_3_1::XMLUri>, std::equal_to<xercesc_3_1::XMLUri>, std::allocator<std::pair<const xercesc_3_1::XMLUri, xercesc_3_1::XMLUri> > >' required here
: public __unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../xx.cpp:6:54: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::unordered_map<xercesc_3_1::XMLUri, xercesc_3_1::XMLUri, std::hash<xercesc_3_1::XMLUri>, std::equal_to<xercesc_3_1::XMLUri>, std::allocator<std::pair<const xercesc_3_1::XMLUri, xercesc_3_1::XMLUri> > >' requested here
    std::unordered_map<xercesc::XMLUri,xercesc::XMLUri> uriMap;
```

I know the unordered containers in C++0x only supply `hash<>` specializations for some of the library types. How do I create the required `hash<xercesc::XMLUri>` specialization for `xercesc::XMLUri`?

EDIT: I came up with this. Does it seem reasonable?

```
#include "xercesc\util\XMLUri.hpp"
#include <string>

namespace std 
{

    size_t hash<xercesc::XMLUri>::operator()(const xercesc::XMLUri& uri) const
    {
        return hash<std::wstring>()(uri.getUriText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. It should be like this (thanks to @jogojapan for pointing out the missing typedefs!):

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>

namespace std
{
    template <> struct hash<xercesc::XMLUri>
    {
        typedef size_t result_type;
        typedef xercesc::XMLUri argument_type;

        size_t operator()(xercesc::XMLUri const & uri) const noexcept
        {
            return hash<wstring>()(uri.getUriText());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This may be an unrelated question but what is the advantage of creating a class template specialization over using a function template specialization?

Comment: @user1626720: you have no choice. `std::hash` *is* a class template.

Comment: A complete specialization for `std::hash` should include definitions for `argument_type` and `result_type` as well (§20.8.12/1). For an example, see the answer I gave yesterday to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13486174/777186

Comment: @KerrekSB : What difference does that make? One can specialize member functions of a class template as though it were a function template.

Comment: @ildjarn: Interesting; good point! The syntax would still be different from what the OP has, namely `template <> size_t hash<X>::operator()(X const &) const noexcept`. But GCC doesn't seem to allow this and only accepts a specialization of the entire class template. Presumably there's no requirement that `operator()` be provided in any particular way; i.e. it could be a base class member function, or come through a proxy object, or whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

`std::hash` is a struct, you must specialize the whole struct, not just the function, then your way of specializing a template is wrong too:

```
namespace std 
{
    template <>
    struct hash<xercesc::XMLUri>
    {
        size_t operator()(const xercesc::XMLUri& uri) const
        {
            return hash<std::wstring>()(uri.getUriText());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `std::hash` is a *template*, not a "struct".

Comment: @KerrekSB, indeed, it's a struct template, I wanted to stress it wasn't a function template.

Comment: A complete specialization for `std::hash` should include definitions for `argument_type` and `result_type` as well (§20.8.12/1). For an example, see the answer I gave yesterday to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13486174/777186

Comment: "*`std::hash` is a struct, you must specialize the whole struct, not just the function*" What? No. His syntax is wrong, but the approach is fine (excepting @jogojapan's correct comment) – [online demo](http://ideone.com/VzepGc).