# Inserting into an unordered_set with custom hash function

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-set

I have the following code to make an `unordered_set<Interval>`. This compiles fine.

```
struct Interval {
  unsigned int begin;
  unsigned int end;
  bool updated;   //true if concat.  initially false
  int patternIndex;  //pattern index. valid for single pattern
  int proteinIndex;   //protein index.  for retrieving the pattern
};

struct Hash {
  size_t operator()(const Interval &interval);
};

size_t Hash::operator()(const Interval &interval){
  string temp = to_string(interval.begin) + to_string(interval.end) + to_string(interval.proteinIndex);
  return hash<string>()(temp);
}

unordered_set<Interval, string, Hash> test;
```

However, I cannot compile when I try to insert using this code:

```
for(list<Interval>::iterator i = concat.begin(); i != concat.end(); ++i){
  test.insert((*i));
}
```

Moreover, I cannot determine what the problem is from the error messages, for example:

```
note: candidate is:
note: size_t Hash::operator()(const Interval&)
note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

I thought I only provided 1 argument...

What is the problem with my insertion code?

---

Here's the new instantiation code: `unordered_set<Interval, Hash> test;`
However, I'm still receiving a slew of error messages, for example:

```
note: candidate is:
note: size_t Hash::operator()(const Interval&) <near match>
note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘const Hash*’ to ‘Hash*’
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key

Comment: @CiroSantilli刘晓波死六四事件法轮功 did you even read the question before commenting that? No you did not.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**First problem:**

You are passing `string` as the second template argument for your instantiation of the `unordered_set<>` class template. [The second argument should be the type of your hasher functor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), and `std::string` is not a callable object.

Perhaps meant to write:

```
unordered_set<Interval, /* string */ Hash> test;
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                      Why this?
```

Also, I would suggest using names other than `begin` and `end` for your (member) variables, since those are names of algorithms of the C++ Standard Library.

**Second problem:**

You should keep in mind, [that the hasher function should be qualified as `const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/hash_function), so your functor should be:

```
struct Hash {
   size_t operator() (const Interval &interval) const {
   //                                           ^^^^^
   //                                           Don't forget this!
     string temp = to_string(interval.b) + 
                   to_string(interval.e) + 
                   to_string(interval.proteinIndex);
     return (temp.length());
   }
};
```

**Third problem:**

Finally, if you want `std::unordered_set` to be able to work with objects of type `Interval`, you need to define an equality operator consistent with your hash function. By default, if you do not specify any type argument as the third parameter of the  `std::unordered_set` class template, `operator ==` will be used.

You currently do not have any overload of `operator ==` for your class `Interval`, so you should provide one. For example:

```
inline bool operator == (Interval const& lhs, Interval const& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.b == rhs.b) && 
           (lhs.e == rhs.e) && 
           (lhs.proteinIndex == rhs.proteinIndex); 
}
```

**Conclusion:**

After all the above modifications, your code becomes:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct Interval {
  unsigned int b;
  unsigned int e;
  bool updated;   //true if concat.  initially false
  int patternIndex;  //pattern index. valid for single pattern
  int proteinIndex;   //protein index.  for retrieving the pattern
};

bool operator == (Interval const& lhs, Interval const& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.b == rhs.b) && (lhs.e == rhs.e) && (lhs.proteinIndex == rhs.proteinIndex); 
}

struct Hash {
   size_t operator()(const Interval &interval) const {
     string temp = to_string(interval.b) + to_string(interval.e) + to_string(interval.proteinIndex);
     return (temp.length());
   }
};

int main()
{
   unordered_set<Interval, Hash> test;
  
  list<Interval> concat;
  for(list<Interval>::iterator i = concat.begin(); i != concat.end(); ++i){
    test.insert(*i);
  }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to wrap `operator ==` in a `struct`?  As it is, I get errors about multiple definitions of `==`.  If I declare it in a `struct` in my header file and define it in my .cpp file (as I'm currently doing for other operators), it gives me errors about it requiring exactly one argument. Ex: `bool IntervalEquality::operator==(const Interval&, const Interval&)’ must take exactly one argument`

Comment: @user2052561: The problem with multiple definition is probably happens because you have that function definition in one header and you are importing it in multiple translation units (i.e. `#include`ing it from several `.cpp` files). Just use the `inline` keyword to suppress this problem (as I show in my updated answer).

Comment: @user2052561: Alternatively, if you want to overload it as a member function, then you should remove the `lhs` parameter, which is implicitly. The `this` pointer will refer to the left hand `Interval` object.

Comment: It's worth noting that this hash function can produce lots of easily-avoidable collisions – an `Interval` with `b == 12` and `e == 3` will produce the same hash as an `Interval` with `b == 1` and `e == 23`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Sure, that's true. My hash function does not have any ambition to be a good hash function - I just wanted to point out what was missing conceptually and provide a minimal working filler.

Comment: Understood – I guess my comment was directed more towards the OP than your answer, sorry for posting it in the wrong place. :-P

Comment: @AndyProwl, I am not very sure whether the hash function and equal function are defined in the customer's class as what java does. Is there a better way that makes these functions related with the class closer ?

Answer (score 3):

I think, Andy Prowl perfectly [fixed the problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15869103/2675154) with your code. However, I would add the following member function to your `Interval`, which describes what makes two intervals identical:

```
std::string getID() const { return std::to_string(b) + " " + std::to_string(e) + " " + std::to_string(proteinIndex); }
```

Please note, that I also followed Andy Prowl's suggestion and renamed the members `begin` to `b` and `end` to `e`. Next, you can easily define the hash and comparison functions by using [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). As a result, you can define your `unordered_set` as follows:

```
auto hash = [](const Interval& i){ return std::hash<std::string>()(i.getID()); };
auto equal = [](const Interval& i1, const Interval& i2){ return i1.getID() == i2.getID(); };
std::unordered_set<Interval, decltype(hash), decltype(equal)> test(8, hash, equal);
```

Finally, for reasons of readability, I converted your `for` loop into a range-based `for` loop:

```
std::list<Interval> concat {{1, 2, false, 3, 4}, {2, 3, false, 4, 5}, {1, 2, true, 7, 4}};

for (auto const &i : concat)
    test.insert(i);

for (auto const &i : test)
    std::cout << i.b << ", " << i.e << ", " << i.updated << std::endl;
```

Output (I just printed first three members of each `Interval`):

> 2, 3, 0
> 1, 2, 0

As you can see, there are only two intervals printed. The third one (`{1, 2, true, 7, 4}`) was not inserted to `test`, because its `b`, `e`, and `proteinIndex`are equal to that of the first interval (`{1, 2, false, 3, 4}`).

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/RTaL7C)