# std::hash vs std::equal_to instantiation without required functions

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, unordered-map

I'm still learning how to use the standard library containers `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`. I have recently tried to provide a *hash* function or *comparison* function.

There are two things I don't understand:

```
std::map<int, int, equal_to<int>> myMap1; // Works
std::map<int, int, hash<int>> myMap2; // Works

std::unordered_map<int, int, equal_to<int>> myMap3; // Doesn't work
std::unordered_map<int, int, hash<int>> myMap4; // Works
```

Why can I provide a hash function for `std::map` while I can't provide a comparison function to a `std::unordered_map`?

Also, if I use a custom struct for the comparison function `std::equal_to` without overloading the `==` operator I get no errors. Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the two structures are very different:

- A hash function makes no sense for a map. A map expects an optional comparison function (it is an ordered structure), your first two examples are not passing a comparison function. It default to less.

To be specific, it is

> Binary predicate that, taking two element keys as argument, returns
>   true if the first argument goes before the second argument in the
>   strict weak ordering it defines, and false otherwise. This shall be a
>   function pointer or a function object. Member type key_compare is the
>   internal comparison object type used by the container, defined in map
>   as an alias of its third template parameter (Compare). If key_compare
>   uses the default less (which has no state), this parameter is not
>   relevant.

- An unordered_map is basically a hashtable (it has no ordered state) and expect a hash function, you are not passing it a hash function.

> Comparison function object, that returns true if the two container
>   object keys passed as arguments are to be considered equal. Member
>   type key_equal is defined in unordered_map as an alias of its fourth
>   template parameter (Pred).

Quotes from http://www.cplusplus.com

Comment: How would I define a hash function then? I have no single idea how.

Comment: For a custom hash function, it has been discussed extensively on SO, for example look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869066/inserting-into-unordered-set-with-custom-hash-function

Comment: The problem is that it is really complex for me. I have found many posts on stackoverflow about hash functions, but never a basic tutorial for beginner like me. For example, can two different variables return the same size_t for a hash function?

Answer (score 3):

There is a thing in Standard C++ Library called "concept". Concept is a set of requirements. By using `std::unordered_map` (or anything that follows a concept, for that matter) you agree that you will adhere to the requirements it states.

By using

```
std::map<int, int, equal_to<int>> myMap1;
std::map<int, int, hash<int>> myMap2;
std::unordered_map<int, int, equal_to<int>> myMap3;
```

you violate requirements both for `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` - compiler isn't required to check for your mistakes, and `myMap1`, `myMap2` and `myMap3` definitely won't work properly.

It just happens that [Hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Hash) requires that it returns value of type `std::size_t`. This can be easily checked.

This is different to [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) that state requirements that cannot easily be checked (for example, `std::size_t` is convertible to `bool`) - therefore, its usage will most likely fail during runtime.

Also, it seems that you are confused about purpose of hash and comparison functions - they are different.

Hash returns an value of type `std::size_t` that for any values `a, b` of type `T`

```
Hash(a) != Hash(b) implies a != b
and
a == b implies Hash(a) == Hash(b)
```

That's it - nothing more, nothing less. It should be faster than a comparison function, so you can easily compare values - if hashes are different, then the values are definitely different, and if hashes are the same, do the full comparison.

Comment: And by the way, if I have a huge struct with like 40 ints in it, how can I combine them into a size_t? Won't there be duplicates?

Comment: Oh never mind. I think I get it now. The hash table in a certain way regroup the keys with the same size_t into buckets (or something like that?).

Comment: @user2924010: Usually, you hash each int, and use a `hash_combine` to combine them into a single hashvalue.  It's ok if two structures have the same hash, but the less it happens the faster the container works.

Comment: Hmmm I'm quite lost here. On [link](www.cplusplus.com), this is the description of size_t:
It is a type able to represent the size of any object in bytes: size_t is the type returned by the sizeof operator and is widely used in the standard library to represent sizes and counts.

Comment: So, if I use a integer key, the size_t will always be the same? Or the  std::hash<> generate a "random" size_t?

Comment: @user2924010 You can't simply generate "random" numbers (also, define what do you mean by "random"), because if you simply generate "random" numbers, `Hash(5) == Hash(5)` won't be true anymore (as required by `a == b implies Hash(a) == Hash(b)`)

Comment: I meant an unknown algorithm generating a size_t based on a pattern.