# Using struct as a type in a C++ template?

Tags: c++

I have a function like so

```
template <typename T>
double vectortest(int n, bool prealloc) {
std::vector<T> tester;
    std::unordered_set<T> seq = generatenums<T>(n);
}
```

Where generatenums is another templatized function

```
template <typename T>
std::unordered_set<T> generatenums(int n) {
  std::unordered_set<T> ret;
}
```

Please note: I have truncated the entire contents of these functions, leaving only what I think is relevant to my question.

I also have a struct

```
typedef struct Filler
{
    int value;
    int padding[2500];
};
```

And I want to be able to invoke my functions like so

```
vectortest<Filler>(5, true);
```

But this generates a lot of errors, and leaves me wondering why I can't use struct as a type for C++ templates, and if there's a way around this?

Comment: First, the `typedef` keyword does not belong there. Remove it. Then it already fails at `std::unordered_set<Filler>`. `std::unordered_set` requires that you define `operator==` and a `std::hash` specialization. Then your `vectortest` and `generatenums` both are missing a return statement and no idea what `tester` is for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use a C++ unordered\_set for a custom class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554083/how-can-i-use-a-c-unordered-set-for-a-custom-class) and [C++ unordered_map using a custom class type as the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key) (`unordered_set` and `unordered_map` have the same requirements)

Comment: You forgot to add the new alias for `typedef`. It is always worth reading what the error says.

Comment: C++'s error messages can be very scary, especially with templates. The way to read them is to scroll to the very top of the errors, and *only* read and handle the first error. Then try again. Most of the "lot of errors" are results of the first error, sort of "trickling down" if you will.

Answer (score 0):

`unordered_set` on structs needs custom hash function.

similarly`uset` on structs needs comparaor `<`operator to be defined.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>


// class for hash function
template <typename T>
struct MyHashFunction {
    // id is returned as hash function
    size_t operator()(const T& f) const
    {
        return f.id;
    }
};

template <typename T>
double vectortest(int n, bool prealloc) {
std::vector<T> tester;
    std::unordered_set<T,MyHashFunction<T>> seq = generatenums<T>(n);
    return 73.0;
}

template <typename T>
std::unordered_set<T,MyHashFunction<T>> generatenums(int n) {
  std::unordered_set<T,MyHashFunction<T>> ret;

  return ret;
}

struct Filler
{
    int id;
    int value;
    int padding[2500];
};



int main(){
  
    
    vectortest<Filler>(5, true);
    return 0;
}
```