# C++ Changing a set default order based of a parameter

Tags: c++, set

I'm trying to modify a functor to accept an argument so I could sort a set based in that parameter. I just can't figure it out

```
struct sortset {
  bool operator() (const string& s1, const string& s2) const {
    //Sorting algorithm depending on "sortingVar"
  }
};

main() {
  string sortingVar; cin >> sortingVar;
  set<string, sortset> mySet;
  ...
}
```

Comment: What type of parameter you want? Also you are missing parenthesis set in your functor; bool operator`()` (const string& s1, const string& s2) const

Comment: Just a simple string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting into unordered\_set with custom hash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869066/inserting-into-unordered-set-with-custom-hash-function)

Comment: @JoanPastor is this string different from the ones you store in your set?

Comment: Yes. Is just a variable saved earlier in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the comparator a constructor which accepts the argument to determine the comparator's behaviour:

```
struct sortset
{
  sortset(const string& sortingVar) : sortingVar(sortingVar) {}

  bool operator() (const string& s1, const string& s2) const {
    //Sorting algorithm based on "sortingVar"
  }
private:
  const string sortingVar;
};

int main() {
  string sortingVar; cin >> sortingVar;

  // Either:
  set<string, sortset> mySet{sortset{sortingVar}};

  // Or:
  sortset comp{sortingVar};
  set<string, sortset> mySet{comp};

  // ...
}
```

Notice that [the set constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set) allows you to provide an actual instance of the comparator, so you can use that to pass one that is not default-constructed (a good thing too, since no such thing can now exist).

Add some `std::move`s if you like.

Don't forget to give `main` a return type.