# Why can't I store my objects in an unordered_set?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-set

I understand a set is ordered, thus adding an object without overloading the `<` operator doesn't allow to say which object is smaller to keep the container sorted. However, I don't understand why this isn't possible with an `unordered_set`.

If I try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string
#include <unordered_set>

struct someType{
    string name;
    int code;
};

int main(){
    std::unordered_set <someType> myset;
    myset.insert({"aaa",123});
    myset.insert({"bbb",321});
    myset.insert({"ccc",213});
    return 0;
}
```

I get a couple of errors like:

> c:\qt\qt5.1.0\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\hashtable_policy.h:1070: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::hash'
>
> c:\qt\qt5.1.0\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\functional_hash.h:58: error: declaration of 'struct std::hash'
>
> error: no matching function for call to 'std::unordered_set::unordered_set()'
>
> c:\qt\qt5.1.0\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\hashtable_policy.h:1103: error: no match for call to '(const std::hash) (const someType&)'
>
> c:\qt\qt5.1.0\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h:208: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'const someType' and 'const someType')

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post the exact code you're using and the exact error message?

Comment: It seems unlikely that that's your actual error. Are you sure you aren't actually using a `set`?

Comment: No, it's an unordered_set. But you're right, that wasn't the exact error. I just edited to add complete code and more detailed error messages. Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ unordered\_map using a custom class type as the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key)

Comment: Just as `std::map` requires `operator<` or a comparator, an `unordered_map` requires both `operator==` and a hash implementation. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key) for details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use type in unordered_set or unordered_map you need hashing function for your type. For common types, like `int` or `std::string` - hashing function is provided by standard library. For your type, you can overload standard `std::hash`, like this:

```
namespace std {
    template <> struct hash<someType> {
        size_t operator()(const someType & x) const {
            std::hash<std::string> h;
            return h(x.name);
            // or simply return x.code
            // or do something more interesting,
            // like xor'ing hashes from both members of struct
        }
    };
}
```

Another way is to provide your own type with overloaded `operator()` and put it as hash template argument in unordered_set, like this:

```
struct someTypeHasher {
    size_t operator()(const someType& x) const {
        return x.code;
    }
};
std::unordered_set<someType, someTypeHasher> myset;
```

Good reading for theory about hash based containers is [here](http://pumpkinprogrammer.com/2014/06/21/c-tutorial-intro-to-hash-tables/)

Also, do not forget, that you need to overload `operator==` for `someType`, without it - it will also not work.

Comment: It would be wise to somehow combine hashes of `name` and `code`, so that `{"aaa", 123}`, `{"aaa", 456}` and `{"bbb", 456}` would have different hash.

Comment: your link is broken

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40751925/2675154) given by *Starl1ght*, you need to provide a hash function for `someType`. However, I would combine all members of your class by that hash function. Otherwise, you might get a lot of collisions, for example, if the same `name` occurs very often, but with different `code` values. For creating a hash function, you can make use of [*Boost*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13486174/2675154), but you can also [handcraft](https://computinglife.wordpress.com/2008/11/20/why-do-hash-functions-use-prime-numbers) it.

*Starl1ght* also mentioned that you need to overload `operator==` for `someType`,
but you can also define a separate comparison function instead and provide it to the `unordered_set`. Moreover, you can use [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of defining the hash and comparison functions. If you put everything together, then your code could be written as follows:

```
auto hash = [](const someType& st){
    return std::hash<std::string>()(st.name) * 31 + std::hash<int>()(st.code);
};
auto equal = [](const someType& st1, const someType& st2){
    return st1.name == st2.name && st1.code == st2.code;
};
std::unordered_set<someType, decltype(hash), decltype(equal)> myset(8, hash, equal);
```

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/7r8KDe)

Comment: Why the "* 31" ?

Comment: @NorbertBoros: Please follow the [handcraft](https://computinglife.wordpress.com/2008/11/20/why-do-hash-functions-use-prime-numbers) link to find a detailed explanation.